# Display Time of Delivery in related.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, template, magento-community

First to the Environment i'm working with:

- Magento Communitiy Edition 1.9.1

**What do i want to do?**

I wanted to add the delivery time of every related product at the related.phtml to display the delivery time unter each related product.

I studied the file an quickly got the point to hook in:

```
<div class="product-details">
    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl()?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName())?>/a></p>
    <?php Mage::register('no_shippingcharges', true); echo this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I've got the single related products wich are looped through with a for loop.
Every $_item-Object seems to be a product and if i load attributes like the id or the name i always get values. But if i want to load the delivery time, with the following one-liner:

```
<?php echo ($_item->getTimeOfDelivery); ?>
```

i don't get any values back.
Even working with the attributetext-method doesn't work:

```
$_item->getAttributeText("time_of_delivery");
```

I've also tried to load the product seperatly with

```
$_product->Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_item->getId());
```

But it also doesn't get me some values.
Is there any other method of getting the "delivery time"-attribute displayed?
I hope someone can give me some advice.

Comment: Did you add the attribute to the product listing? That should make it possible for you to get the attribute in your product lists.

Comment: Dear Arjen,

thanks for your answer.
Yes the attribute is added to the product listing.

Comment: @itreniets Did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm trying to do the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getTimeOfDelivery(), 'time_of_delivery') ?>
```

**Note:** Make sure `time_of_delivery` is product attribute.

Comment: Dear Abdul, thanks for your answer. The time_of_delivery attribute is a product attribute and assigned to the right attributeset.

I've tried the snippet you provided, but unfortunately it doesn't worked. The page was loaded correctly but there was no delivery-time shown.

Comment: Try this : $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
if($_product->getTimeOfDelivery()) {
 echo $_product->getTimeOfDelivery();
}

Comment: Dear Abdul, sorry for the late answer.
i've tested the snippet you provided, but the result was the same.
The $_item-object is existing because i can get the product-id out of it.
The product itself seems to be ok, but the attribute can't be read out. 

I'm not sure but i think i'm overseeing something.

Comment: Did you all ever find a way to do this? I need to do the same...